# Heroku one-click deploy: app.json success_url based on config vars

Tags: heroku

Does anyone know if it's possible to provide custom success_url values in the app.json application manifest?

e.g Given this json I want to construct a success_url in the form http://{ORG_NAME}-example.com

```
{
  "name": "App Name",
  "description": "App Description",
  "repository": "https://github.com/user/repo",
  "env": {
    "ORG_NAME": {
      "description": "Company Name"
    }
    ,
    "SUBDOMAIN": {
      "description": "Your chosen subdomain. If none is chose, ORG_NAME will be used.",
      "required": "false"
    },
  }
}
```

Thanks!